# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.csv'

Tags: python, permissions, traceback

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ty\Dropbox\Level 2 files\combinedfilecreator1.0.py",     line 25, in <module>
    newFile = open('test.csv','w') #This is the new file we're trying to make
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.csv'
```

Everything seems fine, but I don't understand this error I'm getting.

Comment: What is the current directory that the code is executing from?  Can you create a file there?

Comment: yep it was the directory ahahaha thanks