# Problem in reading in a file in r - the number of observations is wronly interpreted as number of variables

Tags: python, r, csv, file-upload, data-science

**What do I want to do:**
I want to read in a file in r that contains 2 variables and 2500 observations for each variable.
The data is an output (list) of a function out of a python project. I have one list for each variable (2 lists with 2500 data points).
I first copied the data in a excel file and transformed it to a csv file and read it in in r.
Since that strategy did not work, I copied the lists in a text file.

**What is my output/problem?**
When I read in the file in r with read.csv() (obviously with the csv file) I get 1 observation but 2500 variables (it should be 2 variables with 2500 observations each).
When I read in the file in r with read.table() I get this error and this warning message:

```
Error in read.table(file = "dataset.txt", header = TRUE) : 
  more columns than column names
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = "dataset.txt", header = TRUE) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader in 'dataset.txt'
```

**What do I think is the problem?**
The data points are side by side and not one below the other.

*Example: 
A=[0.25, 0.67, ...,0.1]
B=[0.03, 0.14, ..., 0.09]*
My guess is that R sees elements that are side by side as variables and all data points that are under the variables as observations and perhaps the first line as heading (so the first line is seen as heading, the second line as 1 observation and all data points that are in the second line are seen as variables).

**What did I try:**
1.  I tried to separate the data points with the sep= ',' function, but that did not change the number of observations or variables (I tried it with a bunch of other signs like ';' '\')
2.  I tried to copy the data points (out of the python print output) into an excel file, but it always put the data points one next to the other and gave me the error that excel only works with maximum ~800 data points.
3.  I tried to create a csv file in the python program with csv.writer() that jumps into a new line after each comma. This gave me an empty file as output, I don’t know why.

```
import csv

with open('dataset.txt','w', newline= '') as csvfile:
    simval_similar = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter= ' ', quotechar=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
print(dataset.txt)
```

4. To prove that my guess (explained in the *‘what do I think is the problem’* section) I rearranged 200 data points such that they are listed one below the other in a text file (manually), that suddenly gave me 200 observations, which means that my guess was probably right (or at least partly). 
   But to do that manually would, first of all, mean that I have to do this for 5000 data points and this strategy is error-prone.
   I don’t know how to continue and would really appreciate help….

Comment: why don't you export the file from python directly to csv? `df.to_csv()`

Comment: I don't see the point in using excel to transfer data between python and R. And if you provide a small reproducible example of the data, you'll get help very quickly here. Read the message after clicking on the [r] tag.

Comment: Hey, tahnk you very much! If I understand it right, the df.to_csv function transforms a pandas dataframe to a csv file. 
To be able to use this function I created a dictionary with my data points and transformed it to a pandas dictionary and used the df.to_csv() function.

Comment: Unfortunatly my problem is still the same. This csv file is as output in my jupyter notebook and I can't load the data into my r environment... 
I tried to download the csv file by writing the path into the function: df.to_csv(path_or_buf=r'path') 
but it gives me an error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\...')

I tried to solve this error but only found that on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426087/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-test-csv
Which was not very helpful for me...

Comment: Regarding my data:
I have a dictionary with tuples on the one side 8always 2 strings) and corresponding similarity values (out of word2vec), which means that the values are numbers between -1 and 1, rouphly normally distributed.
As an example: 
{('house',wife'):0.527,
('lips','window'):0.21,
('elefant','bycicle'): -0.23}
Is this helpful to imagine the data? I can of course copy a small amount of the data in here if this would be better.